# database relations issue

Tags: database, database-design

I have a question regarding my database design and its implementation that i am hoping someone can help me with?

I have a product -> retailer scenario where by the following rules apply:

**product** - many retailers
product - 1 brand

**retailer** - many products

Price can change per retailers

so i have 4 tables

```
product - (Product_ID), product name, brand_ID(FK), details
brand - (Brand_ID), brand name
retailer - (Retailer_ID), retailer_Name, Retailer_Telephone
Retailer_Product - (Product_ID, Retailer_ID), cost,
```

This works fine as you can associate products with reatilers and not all retailers offer all products etc. each product has a set brand.

My issues comes based on the brand:

a retailer can offer 1 or more brands but not necessarily all brands? i am getting an issue implementing this?

So i have created a Retailer_Brand table

```
retailer_brand - (retailer_Id, Brand_ID)
```

Even if you have specified the retailer to brand link i can still enter a product into the retailer product table that is of a brand not associated with the retailer. Am i missing something like a check constraint or is my schema wrong?

Thanks

Rob

**EDIT further details **

I am still not sure if it gives me what I require.

Perhaps If I add the following example it will clarify.

I have a list of products setup that we can offer

e.g. 
Name    Desc    Brand
TV  32 Inch Sony
TV  64 Inch Sony
TV  20 Inch Sony
TV  64 Inch Samsung
TV  32 Inch Samsung
TV  32 Inch Panasonic

Retailers
Uberhardware     - Can sell all brands of tv
SonyRetailer    - Is only allowed to sell Sony products (all products)
PanasonicRetailer - Panasonic Products only

Then along comes a new retailer who I need to setup:
Phoenix Retail  - Is not allowed to sell Sony products

I wish to be able to easily restrict/enable the different brands per retailer?

**EDIT 2**

I have implemented the Alternate key design suggested but i am still able to enter incorrect date see my data setup below and the expected results however all enrtsy into the retailer product table succeed when i would expect some to fail?

**Product**
*ProductID  BrandID*
1   1
2   2

**Brand**
*BrandID*
1
2

**Reatiler**
1
2

**RetailerBrand**
*RetailerID BrandID*
1   1
2   1
2   2
3   1

**RetailerProduct**
*RetaileID  Brand   ProductID   Expected*
1   1   1   OK
1   2   2   FAIL
2   1   1   OK
2   2   2   OK
3   2   2   FAIL

Comment: works on sql server 2008 as is;

Comment: Great all working now, just need to figure out where my datamodler goes wrong in the creation of the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Alternate key (AK) -- unique constraint (with index) on `Product` allows `(ProductID, BrandID)` to be referenced from `RetailerProduct` as a FK.

[image]

```
create table Product (
  ProductID integer not null
, BrandID   integer not null
);
alter table Product add constraint pk_product primary key (ProductID);
alter table Product add constraint un_product unique (ProductID, BrandID);

create table Brand (
  BrandID integer not null
);
alter table Brand add constraint pk_brand primary key (BrandID);

create table Retailer (
  RetailerID integer not null
);
alter table Retailer add constraint pk_retailer primary key (RetailerID);

create table RetailerBrand (
  RetailerID integer not null
, BrandID    integer not null
);
alter table RetailerBrand add constraint pk_retbra primary key (RetailerID, BrandID);


create table RetailerProduct (
  RetailerID integer not null
, ProductID  integer not null
, BrandID    integer not null
);
alter table RetailerProduct add constraint pk_retprd  primary key (RetailerID, ProductID, BrandID);

alter table RetailerProduct add constraint fk1_retprd
      foreign key (ProductID, BrandID) references Product (ProductID, BrandID);

alter table RetailerProduct add constraint fk2_retprd
      foreign key (RetailerID, BrandID) references RetailerBrand (RetailerID, BrandID);
```

**EDIT**

Insert some data

```
insert into Brand    (BrandID)                   values (1)  , (2);
insert into Product  (ProductID, BrandID)        values (1,1), (2,2);
insert into Retailer (RetailerID)                values (1)  , (2);
insert into RetailerBrand (RetailerID, BrandID)  values (1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1);
```

Test

```
insert into RetailerProduct (RetailerID, BrandID, ProductID) values (1,1,1); -- OK

insert into RetailerProduct (RetailerID, BrandID, ProductID) values (1,2,2); -- FAIL

insert into RetailerProduct (RetailerID, BrandID, ProductID) values (2,1,1); -- OK

insert into RetailerProduct (RetailerID, BrandID, ProductID) values (2,2,2); -- OK

insert into RetailerProduct (RetailerID, BrandID, ProductID) values (3,2,2); -- FAIL
```

Comment: thanks, That looks like it will do the job. Do you have anymore details on the AK you have setup is this just a constaint or is it a relation?

Comment: @user1340969; AK is simply a `unique constraint` (with index) -- it is common for DBs to automatically create index for unique constraint.

Comment: is this differnt from a foreign key then? or is it still a forign key but also a uniquie constraint?

Comment: @user1340969 It is unique constraint on `Product` see `un_product`, it is foreign key on `RetailerProduct` see `fk2_retprd`

Comment: Sorry another question, if the product_id is unique per product then is the unique constraint required?

Comment: I have implemented the design as suggested but it doesnt seems to work as expected? See edit above in question?

Comment: @user1340969; There was a typo trying to assign pk from `RetailerBrand` to `Retailer` (duplicate) -- did you get an error? Anyway, drop all tables, copy the code and test again. Just tested here, worked ok.

Comment: thanks just trying it again now. whats the program you generate the diagram from?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I get this right.

**Product**

```
product_id
name
description
etc
```

**Brand**

```
brand_id
name
etc
```

**Retailer**

```
retailer_id
name
etc
```

Relational table
**brand_prod_ret**

```
retailer_id
product_id
brand_id
price
etc
```

For example, Uberhardware retailer sells TVs: LG, Sony, Samsung, etc.

**Uberhardware** goes in the **Retailer** table

**TVs** goes into the **Product** table

You have **product_id** matched with **retailer_id** and **brand_id** in the **brand_prod_ret** table.

Into **brands** you have LG, Sony, Samsung, etc.

and into brand_prod_ret you have

```
TVs' ID - Sony's id -Uberhardware id
TVs' ID - Samsung's id - Uberhardware id
TVs' ID - LG's id - Uberhardware id
```

and of course each price.

[image]

Now you can know exactly which brand the retailer is selling at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, That would allow me to keep track of what brands have been sold but what i am trying to get at is more along the lines of what products are avliable.
e.g. my products  1. tv the brand is sony, 2 - tv  is samsung, tv3 - panasonic etc.. i need to be able to say uberhardware can supply sony, panasonic but not sony and sonysales can sell only sony branded products?

Comment: AH, I understand now. Let me reformulate my answer

Comment: @user1340969 done, you can now get all brands uberhardware sells

Comment: Thanks, i can see what your doing there and it makes sense in terms of seeing which brands a retailer sells but i am not sure it allows me to easily add a new retailer  and associate brands with that retailer? i have added some more comments on my initial Q?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason the brand table is needed in this capacity?

We have many to many relationships with 
products - brand
retailer - retailer_product
brand - retailer brand

Seems you could keep the brand info in the retailer_product table. Then every new brand entered could be pk linked. Or only a retailer to brand look up table to enforce the constraint of a retailer association b/f a new retailer_product can be entered

Answer (score 0):

IMO in your current structure, the table retailer_brand is not strictly necessary, as you can always determine which brands are fully or partially stocked by a retailer by navigating through the retailer_product => product => brand relations.

Can I ask for some clarification on your business domain which might impact your data modelling? (I have some experience at a retailer), e.g.

Brands are often retailer-specific (i.e. a Supplier manufactures a line of products branded purely for one retailer). You might consider adding a Supplier table to your model.

Often stores within the retailer's chain do not stock all products. You might need to consider this in your model.

I'm not sure whether you are on the consumer or supplier facing side of the business, but you may need to model both a cost price and a selling price.

Prices should include Date From / Date To

etc.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I am coming from a reseller point of view we have a selection of products that are of different brands and we get a commision for selling products. i do log teh commision under product but didnt want to confuse the issue. Each retailer we deal with offers differnt brands e.g. retailer a will stock brand 1,2,3 retailer b will only stock brand 1. i want to be able to enforce these rules in the database so that i can easily add a brand to a retailer. so if retailer b starts stocking brand 2 as well these products are added?